# python background parallel file reader/writer

Tags: python, file, background, parallel-processing, loading

I have what I think is a fairly simple problem, but I can't seem to get it to work as I'd hoped.  I have ~200 ~200 MB files, enough that I can't load them all into memory at once.  Each file needs to be processed with each other file once (so ~20000 operations of the processing function).  I need to loop through files multiple times, in something like:

```
for i in xrange(len(file_list)-1): #go through each file
    if i==0: 
        f = read(file_list[i])   #load in the first file
    else:
        f = g0  #we've already loaded in the next file once, don't re-load it
    for j in xrange(i+1,len(file_list)): #go through each other file to get all unique pairs
        g = read(file_list[i+j+1])  # takes 5 s
        answer.append(processing_function(f,g)) # takes 10s
        if j==0:
           g = g0 # this will be "f" for the next iteration of the outer loop
```

The outer loop only needs to load file 1, then it can take an already-loaded file from the first iteration of the inner loop as its next value.  The inner loop needs to load (len(file_list)-i) files and process them.  Since I can't keep ~200 files in memory, and there's no simple way to break up the file list (since each one needs to be paired with each other one exactly once)

Is there an obvious way to parallelize the read() function such that it's reading in at least the next file, i.e. g_j+1 during the execution of processing_function(f_i,g_j)?  I've tried both threading and multiprocessing, and I've been able to offload the reading into a different thread/process, but it doesn't ever run in parallel (i.e. the execution of processing_function() starts as soon as I get a g, while future g_j's are being loaded in the background).  I've either managed to hang the program (using multiprocessing), or just load up a bunch of files into the queue before processing_function() ever runs on the first one (using threading).

I hope this is simple to execute and I'm just messing up a detail.

This is what I've tried so far (from code someone suggested elsewhere) -- it *seem* like this should do what I want, but like I said, it seems that the file_worker method in QueuedFileReader() goes through and puts up to QUEUE_SIZE files into the queue before giving back control to the loop for which QueuedFileReader is the generator.  It would be perfect if file_worker would just run on its own and the loop using QueuedFileReader() could proceed once a single file is ready in the queue for the next() call...

```
class QueuedFileReader():
    def __init__(self,file_list,tmp_dir,QUEUE_SIZE):
        self.queue =Queue.Queue(QUEUE_SIZE)                                                                           
        self.worker = threading.Thread(target=QueuedFileReader.file_worker,args=(self.queue,file_list,tmp_dir))                             
        #self.queue = multiprocessing.Queue(QUEUE_SIZE)
        #self.worker = multiprocessing.Process(target=QueuedFileReader.file_worker,args=(self.queue,file_list,tmp_dir))
        self.worker.daemon=True
        self.worker.start()

    @staticmethod
    def file_worker(queue,file_list,tmp_dir):
        for i,f in enumerate(file_list):
            done = False
            while True and not done:
                try:
                    print "attempting to read %s"%f_in
                    queue.put((i,f_in,files.read(f)))
                    print "successfully read in %s"%f
                    done = True
                except Queue.Full:
                    pass
        queue.put('done')

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        N = 0
        while True:
            try:  
                x = self.queue.get()
                break
            except Queue.Empty:
                pass
        if x == 'done': raise StopIteration
        return x

    def __del__(self):
        self.worker.join()
```

That is called from:

```
for j,fnm,g in QueuedFileReader(flz[i+1:],tmp_dir,QUEUE_SIZE):
    #the code that runs on object "f" from the outer loop and "g" that should be supplied off the top of the queue on each next() call to QueuedFileReader()
```

Comment: A complete hack, but in a similar situation, what I did was `os.system("cp bigfile /dev/zero &")`...  This runs in the background and preloads the whole file in the cache.

Comment: Another note is that you end up doing ~20000 file reads in your solution.  It may not matter if loading is done in parallel and takes less than the processing time, but if it does, then it's possible to improve: e.g. if the memory can hold 20 files instead of 2, then you can load 10 files in f[0]..f[9] and 10 in g[0]..g[9] and do all cross-computations of them.  This reduces the number of file reads to ~2000 (but you need to be careful to get things right, of course).

Comment: The problem with `multiprocessing` is that you'd have to share the 200MB of read-in data between the child and parent processes. If you do that via shared memory or mmap, it's exactly the same as just mmaping the file in the first place; if you do it via a pipe/queue/whatever, you're probably adding more overhead than you're saving. So, the only benefit you could get is the accidental benefit of pre-caching (which, as Armin Rigo suggests, you can get more simply).

Comment: A better way to parallelize this might be to break the input down into groups of file-pairs and run those groups in parallel. So, to start off with, process 0 is comparing file 0 vs. files 1, 2, ..., 100, while process 1 is comparing file 100 vs. files 101, ..., 200. Eventually of course, process 0 will have to read file 101 to compare to file 0, but they can stay away from each other _most_ of the time. If you get the number of processes right, you should usually have one or more processes working while the others are blocked on I/O.

Comment: But it should be relatively easy to do this the way you described with `threading`. If you show us your code, it should be possible to figure out what you're doing wrong. But keep in mind that, with Python before 3.2, having one CPU-bound thread can really screw up I/O-bound thread performance, so it may not be worth it. You'd have to test to find out. (You can always fix that by moving the I/O and preprocessing into GIL-less C, e.g., by using `numpy` or `pandas` instead of pure Python, or by writing your own Cython code…)

Comment: Sorry, getting a bit off, but I couldn't resist: http://bpaste.net/show/89990/ is a program showing that you can do all pairs of 200 files, assuming you have enough RAM for 20 of them, in a total of 1154 loads only. :-)